# Android app launcher icon actual size

Tags: android, icons, size, launcher

According to android info over the web app launcher sizes should be following:

```
48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
```

But when I make screenshot from my Nexus5 actual pixel size is different (180x180 for xxhdpi), looks like Lollipop use different icon size.

**What I mean:**
[image: Problem]

P.S.
I am using default android launcher, no mods or accessibility settings.

Answer (score 2):

Some devices scale-up the launcher icon by as much as 25%. For example, if your highest density launcher icon image is already extra-extra-high density, the scaling process will make it appear less crisp. So you should provide a higher density launcher icon in the `mipmap-xxxhdpi` directory, which the system uses instead of scaling up a smaller version of the icon.

Note: The `mipmap-xxxhdpi` qualifier is necessary only to provide a launcher icon that can appear larger than usual on an xxhdpi device. It is best practice to place all your launcher icons in the `res/mipmap-[density]/` folders. This enables your app to display launcher icons that have a higher density than the device, without scaling up a lower density version of the icon. You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I did all sizes with android icons generator and was confused when compared mipmap-xxhdpi icon with taken screenshot. Now it's clear.

Comment: Well, the difference between xxxhdpi and xxhdpi is 33%, not 25%. That means a device like the Nexus 5 won't pick up the xxxhdpi version but it will scale up the xxhdpi version by 25% - obviously resulting in a blurry image. It's a pity that it still seems to be impossible to provide pixel perfect launcher icons!